# Convert unix time to datetime in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a JSON like:

```json
{
  "id": 1
  "create_time" : 1692617669
}
```

How can i convert this to **`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`** with **GMT+3** timezone with **`UpdateRecord`**?

I tried with **`${field.value:multiply(1000):format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "GMT+3")}`**

[image]

Bot got an error:

```java
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2023-07-20 16:28:28"
```

So i need to change data type to string - for this i should create new field.
I tried with Record Path Value as Replacement Value Strategy

But got an error + invalid date:
[image]

Error:

```java
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1970-01-20 13:24:19"
```

How to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate the same flow on my end

[image: Generate Flowfile]

[image: UpdateRecord]

`${field.value:multiply(1000):formatInstant("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", "GMT+3")}`

[image: Final Flow]

[image: Final Output]

If you really need the file to be in Avro format then the following properties needs to be set.

[image: AvroRecordWriter]

```json
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "CustomRecord",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "create_time",
      "type": {
        "type": "string",
        "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The issue seems to be with the AvroRecordSetWriter probally with the Schema Inheritance.